# How can I target the window.scrollY value of a scrollable react component chart?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In one of my Next/React App pages, I render a scrollable chart as seen below

[image]

I want to be able to fire a function only when the user has scrolled to the very bottom of the chart.

I know window.scrollY will be based on the outer scrollbar, not the inner one in the chart.

How can I measure the window.scrollY value of the inner chart?

Or is there a better way to know when the user has reached the bottom of the chart instead of using the window Y value?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava the dropdowns are not divs but I use Material UI. Would targetting divs still apply in this case?

Please revive my Q

Comment: You need to target the parent element that contains all the dropdowns and other text. The scrollbar appears on that element.